# Como posso obter reputação de +8 em resposta sem aparente voto negativo?

Tags: suporte, respostas, votos, reputação

Recentemente eu redigi uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/250757/64969) que obteve reputação de +8. Ela existe (segundo o relógio UTC +0 da SE) desde hoje dia 30/10/2017, então toda interação que tiveram com a resposta foi de hoje ainda.

Com essa reputação, resolvi o seguinte sistema linear inteiro:

```
reputação = 10* up - 2*down
pontuação = up - down
```

Ainda não tinha visto pontuação, mas para pontuação as seguintes opções me pareciam razoáveis:

```
1 up, 1 down
2 ups, 6 downs
...
n + 1 ups, 5*n + 1 downs
```

Ou seja, esperava encontrar uma reputação ao menos zero, talvez negativa (mas pelo pouco tempo de vida, eu duvidava que teria muitos votos negativos para justificar `n >= 1`):

```
reputação = n+1 - (5*n + 1) = n-5*n + 1-1 = -4*n
```

Porém, ao abrir a resposta ela apareceu com reputação positiva (e sem downvotes):

[image: resposta mostrando a existência de apenas um upvote]

Quando fui na aba de reputação, tem dois eventos relacionados a essa resposta:

[image: 2 eventos: 1 voto a favor e 1 voto contra]

Essas informações não estão mutuamente contraditórias? Como posso ter um voto a favor e um voto contra, sendo que só tenho um voto a favor?

Já tentei limpar o cache do navegador e abrir em sessão anônima, todos apontam para essa mesma informação. (Na sessão anônima, eu não me loggei, então não pude ver os votos positivos/negativos, apenas a reputação líquida, mas continua contando os mesmos dois eventos para essa resposta).

---

Segundo a hora mostrada dos eventos, o voto contra foi feito 1h30 depois do voto a favor.

> Horário do voto a favor: 8:10:13z
>   Horário do voto contra: 9:37:22z

Não me parece ser o caso apontado pelo @Stormwind e pelo @Renan em seus comentários [1](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6515/como-posso-obter-pontua%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-8-em-resposta-sem-aparente-voto-negativo#comment25217_6515) [2](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6515/como-posso-obter-pontua%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-8-em-resposta-sem-aparente-voto-negativo#comment25219_6515) devido a essa diferença temporal, mas posso estar enganado.

---

O @Bacco [sugeriu no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40849429#40849429) que pode ter sido uma espécie de desconto natural de votos positivos recebidos/votos negativos dados:

> [...] mas essa sua pontuação pode ser só o "desconto natural" do sistema, quando você dá alguns negativos e depois recebe um positivo

Porém isso não condiz com o histórico de votos negativos do meu perfil. O meu último voto contra foi a uma pergunta (que não precisa de contrapartida de reputação minha), a penúltima foi a uma resposta:

[image: meus dois últimos votos contra]

> Data/hora do último voto contra (pergunta): 2017-10-28 18:18:06z
>
> Data/hora do penúltimo voto contra (resposta): 2017-10-28 18:13:47z

Ainda assim, o voto contra a resposta foi dado a uma resposta que já foi removida, então minha reputação deveria ter sido restaurada.

---

## UPDATE

Depois de eu remover a foto do órgão e do bicho, os votos negativos foram desfeitos...

Também fui informado pelo @rray que havia levado sinalizações de conteúdo impróprio. E também pode ser o tempo que o @GuilhermeNascimento falou sobre o *back-end cache*.

O mais engraçado para mim é que simplesmente apareceu o `+2` no símbolo do troféu mas na verdade o que estava `+36` virou `+40`. *Alea jacta est*.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas as vezes as pessoas "*ficam brincando com o voto*", a favor e contra em poucos segundos deixando o sistema meio maluco. Não sei quando ocorreu, mas espere um pouco e veja o que acontece.

Comment: Não parece ser o caso... O voto a favor foi 8h10, o contra 9h37... Só se a pessoa que votou contra se arrependeu e removeu o voto deixando o sistema de reputação louco?

Comment: Já passei pelo que o Stormwind falou, é isso mesmo. Agora, a pessoa só teria conseguido mudar voto dentro de cinco minutos se não houver edição da publicação.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado dado a diferença de horário, não pode mais ser a minha suposição. Sem ideias até... Agora é esperar uma explicação dos moderadores e/ou relacionados com acesso as ferramentas de moderação para apurar esse caso.

Comment: Vou insistir em uma coisa que as vezes as pessoas discordam, bug no back-end-cache, pra mim aparece o tal downvote, se ainda não aparece pra ti suponho que seja um "BUG".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tem certeza que não é o segundo negativo que acabei de levar? Estou com +16 de reputação nessa questão bem agora, saldo de pontos +1

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado estou me baseando no seu "print", que não mostra o downvote, até então se agora aparecem 2 downvotes e 2 upvotes quando clica pra ver os detalhes na resposta, então está correto 10+10-2-2=16, se os downvotes aparecem somente na sua tela de "eventos", então tem um bug.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vou tirar um novo print assim que estiver com o computador em mãos

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado mas aparece na postagem +2/-2 ? E o score total é 16?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Observe como pra mim aparece +2/-1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQV5l.png ... logo seria 10+10-2 = 18, então algo esta com problema mesmo... outra coisa será que o 16 não seriam dois downvotes que você deu em duas diferentes respostas?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sem downvotes dados desde o dia 28, vide última atualização

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado viu o print?

Comment: **Nota:** Jeff, se você falasse de seios provavelmente teria uns 20 upvotes = 100 pontos

Comment: Apareceu um voto negativo agora \o/ Mas ainda sinto falta do outro. E coincidiu o novo voto negativo chegar com um voto positivo. Não entendo mais nada

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pode ter sido alguém testando o downvote e upvote e removeu em seguida

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme [esta resposta no MSE indica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270811/208518):

> Isto acontece quando alguém sinaliza a tua publicação como spam/ofensiva, e a sinalização é rejeitada. O voto automaticato deixado pelo utilizador Community é invalidado imediatamente e a tua reputação corrigida, mas por alguma razão o evento do voto não é removido do teu histórico de reputação.
>
> O sistema corrige isto sozinho através de um processo que corre às 03:00 UTC e que remove estes eventos "fantasma" que não deviam existir no teu histórico de reputação.

Answer (score 4):

Pra fazer as contas no horário de 16:18 UTC

Postagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- 3 ups = 30
- 1 down = -2

no perfil:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- 3 ups = 30
- 2 downs = -4

Logo pode ser realmente um BUG, talvez o sistema não seja perfeito para "desfazer" e talvez depois de um tempo role uma limpeza para ajustar problemas disto (me lembrei do "Orkut não sabe contar").

Outra possibilidade pode ser o cache-back-end que as vezes não funciona como esperado, afinal como conversei contigo nos comentários, tua visualização é diferente da minha.